# Dynamically fill an array

Tags: php

i want to fill my array Dynamically.

In the End it should be looking like that

```
$data = array(
    'spalte' => 'Bezeichnung'
    'sort'=>'desc'
    'seitennr'=>'1'
        'Filter' => 'Filter',
        'Ei' => 'on',
     'Erdnuss' => 'on',
        'Gluten' => 'on',
        'Laktose' => 'on',
        'Tomate' => 'on',   
 );
```

If I just use

```
$spalte='Bezeichnung'

array_push($data, $spalte);
```

it will just give me

```
$data=
(
    [0] => Bezeichnung
)
```

Anyone knows how 2 format it corectly ? Sry I am pretty new 2 PHP but i need this for Dynamic Site creation with [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Thx for your help

Comment: `$data['spalte'] = $spalte` !?!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to construct is an associative array. I believe this will work instead of `array_push`

```php
$data['spalte'] = $spalte;
```